# How to display base64 string as image in email, using AWS SES

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am trying to show an image inside my e-mail. But that image is not getting displayed. I am using base64 string, which I am fetching from S3 bucket.

I am able to get email in inbox, but only thing image is not working when passing url, if directly using base64 hard coded string in html its working.

I need to fetch image from s3 and that image should be inline with email.

```js
"use strict";
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path")
const Handlebars = require('handlebars');
const {SESClient, sendEmailCommand} = require("@aws-sdk/client-ses");
const {S3Client, GetObjectCommand} = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");

let S3=null, SES=null;

const streamToBuffer = async(stream) =>{
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
    const chunks = [];
    stream.on("data", (chunk) =>{chunks.push(chunk)});
    stream.on("error", reject);
    stream.on("end", () =>{resolve(Buffer.conact(chunks))});
  })
}


export.handler = async(event) =>{
  if(S3 === null){
    S3 = new S3Client ({region: MY_REGION})
  }
  
  if(SES === null){
    SES = new SESClient ({region: MY_REGION})
  }
  try{
   let deatils = event.detail.fullDocument;
   
   let imageKey = `${deatils.dir}/myimage.png`;
   
   let imageFileFromS3 = await S3.send(
                         new GetObjectCommand({
                         Bucket: MY_BUCKET_NAME, key: imageKey 
                         }))
   let imageFileBuffer = await streamToBuffer(imageFileFromS3.Body)
   let bufferToBase64 = imageFileBuffer.toString("base64");
   
   const emailSubject = "Hey!! Test mail with image";
   const emailData = {
    Name: "Email Tester"
    ImageSrc: `data:image/png;base64, ${bufferToBase64}`
   }
   
   let htmlTemplate =       Handlebars.complie(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'templateSrc', email.html)).toString())
   
   let textTemplate = Handlebars.complie(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'templateSrc', email.txt)).toString())
   
   let emailResult = await SES.send( new SendEmailCommand({
    Source: "Source_test@email.com", //dummy email for now
    Destination :{
      ToAddress: ["to_test@email.com"] // dummy address 
    },
    Message: {
      Subject: {
        Charset: 'UTF-8',
        Data: emailSubject
      },
      Body: {
        Text: {
          Charset: 'UTF-8',
          Data: textTemplate(emailData)
        },
        Html:{
          Charset: 'UTF-8',
          Data: htmlTemplate(emailData)
        }
      }
    }
   }))
   return emailResult
  }catch(error){
    console.log(error)
  }
  
  
}
```

```css
email.txt

Dear {{Name}}

Thanks for asking images on email.

Please find your requested images below
   
 Face image

 Bus image

   -----Thanks
```

```html
Email.html

<h1>Dear {{Name}}</h1>
<p>Thanks for asking images on email.</p>
<p>Please find your requested image below</p>

 <p>face Image</p>
 <img src={{ImageSrc}} />

  <p>Bus Image</p>
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,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">

//This image is working
 
<p>-------Thanks</p>
```

[image]

Comment: did you compare the html? what is the diff?

Comment: Only the way of using image is different..like first one is from S3 and second one is Direct url with base64 string

Comment: I don't understand. Please compare the complete html of both mails. Then paste the difference.

Comment: There is no other html. I am using the same html... In the html there are two images, One image is getting displayed and another one is not. The one which is working is hard coded one. In the code template i  have added email. please have a look on comments inline with image tag

Comment: I do understand that, but after your template has been processed there will not be a `{{Name}}` and `{{ImageSrc}}` anymore, but the output will be some html. I want to see this output.
If in the html neither `{{Name}}` nor `{{ImageSrc}}` get replaced by actual content something seems to be wrong with your templating

Comment: In other words post the output of `htmlTemplate(emailData)`.

Comment: If I will share the screenshot of email that I have recieved in the inbox would that work for u??

Comment: I have updated question with screenshot. And  I am trying log that htmlTemplate(emailData), in cloud watch logs it's getting generated in string format.

Comment: dependent on what mail client you use you can also view the html page source for the email. For Thunderbird e.g. see https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1233376

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just resolved this issue...
So I thought, about posting answer for others help.

The root cause of this was- large size of my buffer response form S3, and email only supports 128MB data, as I found in cloud watch logs ( I can comment about AWS SES only, not sure about other email clients)

So the ultimate solution for my problem is just to resize the buffer response, which we are getting from S2.

So I have used sharp https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp

And add these line in index.js

//Here I will resize the image

const resizedImageFileBuffer =
await sharp(imageFileBuffer)
.resize ({
width:200,
height:200,
fit: 'contain'
})
.toFormat('png')
.png({
quality:100,
compressionLevel: 6
})
.toBuffer()

//Now we will convert resized buffer to base64
let bufferToBase64 =
resizedImageFileBuffer.toString("base64");